# Counter-example to tonelli's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I don't understand why [this example](https://planetmath.org/counterexampletotonellistheorem) doesn't satisfy the conditions of the Tonelli result. It is said that the space are not $\sigma$-finite. But isn't the counting measure and the Lebesgue measure $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: How do you get $[0,1]$ with counting measure is $\sigma$-finite?  The only sets of finite measure are finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting measure is not sigma finite. We cannot write $[0,1]$ as a **countable** union of **finite** sets.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I was confusing $\sigma$-additivity and $\sigma$-finiteness